# Vscode plug-ins - HTML CSS Support: how to configure

Tags: html

My settings.json configuration is as follows:

`[
    "editor.parameterHints": true,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": true
    },
]`

Properties that cannot be prompted for multiple property values, such as: border: 1px solid # FFFFFF;Solid properties are not prompted. How to set the property values to automatically prompt for whitespace like webstorm.CTRL + space doesn't work for me either.